# In angularJs: what's the different between setting $watch on string variable and setting $watch on Object's key?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

In angularJs: what's the different between setting $watch on string variable and setting $watch on Object's key?

The detail scenario is as follow:

```
$scope.activedMenu = {'id' : '...', 'name' : 'menu1'};
$scope.selectedMenuName = 'menu1';
$scope.$watch('activedMenu.name', function () {...});
$scope.$watch('selectedMenuName', function () {...});
```

So, my question is what's the different between "$scope.$watch('activedMenu.name', function () {...})" with "$scope.$watch('selectedMenuName', function () {...})"? Any help will be appreciated!

(I think these two ways to set a $watch are equivalence, I refer from the scope develop guide! https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: you seem to be confused.  both `$watch` statements are identical other than the parameter they are watching; and in your case, `selectedMenuName` and `activatedMenu.name` aren't even the same object, so the obvious difference here is the data they are monitoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `$watch` need string parameter & search for that parameter inside current scope & placed dirty watch on it.

Watching on `activedMenu.name` **OR** `selectedMenuName` is one as the same thing, 1st one will watch on `name` property of  `activedMenu`, the 2nd one will watch on `selectedMenuName` scope variable.

The only difference I think is you are watching on single property so you can use object equality option here which deep watches the object change. It could be possible for you 1st watch but watch string should be `activedMenu` only

```
$scope.$watch('activedMenu', function(newVal, oldVal){
   //on watch code here
}, true);
```

Comment: When you use the deep watch way, It's most expensive. So, I prefer Watching by reference way.

Comment: @bill I just gave an example, not preferring to use deep watch..just for explaination